# Exporting a python dataframe + text element to an image

Tags: python, pandas

I want to print a data frame as a png image, and followed the following approach.

```
import pandas as pd
import dataframe_image as dfi

data = {'Type': ['Type 1', 'Type 2', 'Type 3', 'Total'], 'Value': [20, 21, 19, 60]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
dfi.export(df, 'table.png')
```

I however want to also print a date stamp above the table on the image - with the intention of creating a series of images on consecutive days. If possible I would also like to format the table with a horizontal line indicating the summation of values for the final 'Total' row.

Is this possible with the above package? Or is there a better approach to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the line `df.index.name = pd.Timestamp('now').replace(microsecond=0)` to add the timestamp on the first row:

[image]

To add the line you can use `.style.set_table_styles`:

```
data = {'Type': ['Type 1', 'Type 2', 'Type 3'], 'Value': [20, 21, 19]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.index.name = pd.Timestamp('now').replace(microsecond=0)
df.loc[len(df)] = ['Total',df['Value'].sum()]
test = df.style.set_table_styles([{'selector' : '.row3','props' : [('border-top','3px solid black')]}])
dfi.export(test, 'table.png')
```

[image]